# "Tell me what you know"

Tags: knowledge

How can you possibly answer a broad question, "Tell me what you know.", without referring to any specific aspect of knowledge.

Comment: "I know what I know"

Comment: This request/order has a head or a tail. "Tell me what you know about .....". Then the answer will be narrowed. Otherwise you should ask him to narrow the topic.

Comment: This is unclear. Wait... is this a broad question? Ha...I see what' you're doing.

Comment: You can't, so you'd have to answer with a refusal.

Comment: It's odd that this question is on hold for being too broad since that is exactly the whole point of the question.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to the means of acquisition of knowledge: I know what I’ve directly experienced under suitable conditions and what I’ve learned through reliable testimony.